# Segmentation Fault: 11 Assembly

Tags: assembly

Why do I get a segmentation fault from the following code?

```
.text
        .globl  start
start:
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        movq    $0xBEEFF00DBEEFF00D, %rax
        pushq   %rax
        movq    $0xF00DBEEFF00DBEEF, %rax
        pushq   %rax
        movq    %rbp, %rsp
        popq    %rbp
        ret
```

Error:

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Comment: What's the point of this code?

Comment: None. But I am learning and I wonder why this does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `start` is your program's entry point, you can't `ret` to OS; you should `_exit`.

On Linux (x86-64) which you're probably using, do this instead of `ret`:

```
    movq $60, %rax # %rax = _exit() system call
    xorq %rdi, %rdi # %rdi = 0 normal program return code
    syscall
```